# How do I make browser shortcuts w/custom proxy settings available on user desktops?

Tags: active-directory, proxy, group-policy, shortcut

In our environment, we have about 30 testers (website testers) located at different physical locations. However, they all log on to the same AD.

As it is now, their MSIE is configured to access the Internet through a proxy. However, I need these testers to also be able to launch MSIE, Chrome and FireFox configured with a different proxy. These shortcuts should be in addition to the existing MSIE shortcut with the default proxy.

Is this possible to do via AD Group Policy? That is, create additional shortcuts to the browsers with separate settings?

Comment: Chrome uses the same proxy configuration that IE does. You're not going to get IE and Chrome configure differently at the same time on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla uses prefs.js to store there Preferences including Proxy paths.
Depending on What Client OS you use they are stored under different paths in the user profile.
What you could do is you create a Firefox Profile with different settings, store it on the network somewhere and create a little script on there desktop.

This script then overwrites the prefs.js with your version with the new proxy settings.

You can also create different profiles, have a script copy them to the local machine in the path where firefox stores its profiles and then start firefox with the -P  option.

Would that be a solution??